# Validação com JSF

Tags: jsf, validação, jsf-2.2

Quero realizar a validação do formulário exibido na imagem de uma forma diferente da que o framework me impõe. A validação seria algo como um alerta, ou seja, o usuário seria informado de que só pode adicionar dados se selecionar uma opção do combo. Essa validação deve ocorrer após o clique no botão Adicionar. Algo como: "Selecione uma opção antes de adicionar". Isso é possível sem uso de JavaScript? Como fazer?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando o Primefaces.

No seu SelectOneMenu teria as seguintes propriedades:

- uma property chamada required="true" que diria que o campo é obrigatório.
- uma property chamada requiredMessade="Sua mensagem" onde você diria qual mensagem você quer adicionar.

Acima do seu form teria um campo de mensagens para ser mostradas, que poderia ser assim:

```
<p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
```

No seu botão precisaria adicionar as seguintes propriedades:

- ajax="true" para fazer a validação utiliando o ajax.
- immediate="false" (caso for true ele não fará as validações de tela)

Ou caso você não queira utilizar o primefaces, poderia colocar após o clique do botão, no seu Bean, uma mensagem utilizando o Faces, dessa forma:

```
FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Qual a mensagem", "O que dizer na mensagem");
```

Qualquer dúvida você pode checar no próprio site do primefaces:

http://www.primefaces.org/

Comment: Olá @Dante, o atributo "ajax" vem definido com "true" por padrão mano.

Comment: @ColdHack é verdade, não lembrei desse detalhe, mas a informação foi passada pelo menos. Obrigado pela correção!

Answer (score 2):

Tem como fazer o que você quer.

Primeiramente adicione isso no seu XHTML:

```
<p:growl id="messageGrowl" />
```

Em seguida, no método disparado pelo botão **Adicionar**, após fazer a devida validação, adicione a seguinte linha de código para disparar uma mensagem na página:

```
FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Mensagem", "Descrição");
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
```

Para maiores detalhes, [clique aqui](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/growl.xhtml).